# Forcing Margins to UIImageView in UICollectionView Cell

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm looking for a way to force a UIImageView inside a collection view cell to maintain 8 points margins, similar to this picture:
[image]

It doesn't work all the time, sometimes it crosses the right edge like this:
[image]

The image view is set to AspectFill because I want it to fill the space without distorting it. Here is how it looks in Xcode:
[image]

I want to force 8 points margin in all sides except for the bottom.

Comment: Is `clipsToBound` property of the `UIImageView` set to YES?

Comment: Thank you, the problem solved when I unchecked Clip to Bounds option on the image view, but now it expands to left and right edges and only top margin shows up.

Comment: Check the `contentMode` of the imageView.